# Output a PHP Array into Unordered List?

Tags: php, arrays

This is clearly an simply item, and several existing questions here about the task, but when trying those solutions it results in errors.

In WordPress, I have an array that when printed shows the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Dog
            [slug] => dog
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
            [taxonomy] => wpsl_store_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 7
            [name] => Cat
            [slug] => cat
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 7
            [taxonomy] => wpsl_store_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 4
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [name] => Horse
            [slug] => horse
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
            [taxonomy] => wpsl_store_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

Trying to echo the array into an unordered list of the [name] for each.

So when doing `<?php echo $myArray; ?>` it should output

```
<ul>
<li>Dog</li>
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Horse</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To the person who downgraded the question, please be sure to post a comment on how it can be improved, as otherwise will not know how to better write the question. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your array is containing some term objects. Suppose the array is `$term_objs` then you can use the following code to print the term names,

```
foreach ($term_objs as $term_obj ):
    echo '<li>'.$term_obj->name.'</li>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Your a life saver, that's worked! I had the for each and the end for each, based on other posts on SO, but couldn't get the middle part working since all the other examples on the site didn't seem to apply. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**This Work for me**

```
<?php
$ul = '<ul>';
foreach ($abc as $key => $value) {
    $ul.= '<li>'.$value->item.'</li>';
}
$ul .= '</ul>';
?>
```